# How to set the kivy spinner buttons to an own button class by using the kv language?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to set the buttons inside of the spinner UI. Some pseudo example below:

```
<TemplButton@Button>:
    background_normal: 'gfx/button_bgr.png'
    background_down: 'gfx/button_act.png'

<TemplSpinner@Spinner>:
    background_normal: 'gfx/button_bgr.png'
    background_down: 'gfx/button_act.png'
    dropdown_cls: TemplButton
    option_cls: TemplButton
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: And what happens when you try to run this?

Comment: the python interpreter brings an error: "NameError: name 'TemplButton' is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Factory` to access the dynamic class + create a subclass of the SpinnerOption(Button) class

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<TemplButton@Button>:
    background_normal: 'gfx/button_bgr.png'
    background_down: 'gfx/button_act.png'

<TemplSpinnerOption@SpinnerOption>
    background_normal: 'gfx/button_bgr.png'
    background_down: 'gfx/button_act.png'

<TemplSpinner@Spinner>:
    background_normal: 'gfx/button_bgr.png'
    background_down: 'gfx/button_act.png'
    option_cls: Factory.TemplSpinnerOption
```